# php xpdf read and display file from other server

Tags: php

```
$pdf = new xPDF();
$i=1;//by pady
$pgknt=$pdf->setSourceFile($filename);

while($i<=$pgknt) { //by pady
  $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($i);//by pady
  $pdf->AddPage();//by pady
  $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx);

  $pdf->SetFont('Times','B',10);
  $pdf->SetX(48);
  $pdf->cell(80,10,$headr,0,0,'L');
  $i++;
}
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
header('Cache-Control: maxage=3600'); //Adjust maxage appropriately
header('Pragma: public');
$pdf->Output($fname, 'I');
```

This is working well for local server.
Suppose i have pdf file on other server, example:

```
path = 'http://11.146.11.111/data/pdfs/
```

Can is show the pdf's from this server using above code